# Text in a button not changing on ng-click

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

I have a button whose text is a binding expression.
It has a `ng-click` directive which is a function to change the value of the expression.
However, it doesn't work.

What's wrong here?

Here is my plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/EScqj0iczpH65tstokia

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="test">

<head>
     <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.4.0-rc.0" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0-rc.0/angular.js"></script>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
     <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <button ng-click="start()"> {{ myText }} </button>
</body>
```

JS

```
angular.module('test',[])
  .controller('MyCtrl',function ($scope) {
    $scope.myText = 'Press to start';
    $scope.start = function () {
      $scope.myText = 'Starting...';
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you got a little confused. In your `script.js`, you didn't define a `start()` function, but you called one in your `ng-click` directive. Instead, you created a `starting()` function.

This should work:

```
angular.module('test',[])
  .controller('MyCtrl',function ($scope) {
    $scope.myText = 'Press to start';
    $scope.start = function () {
      $scope.myText = 'Starting...';
    }
});
```

Comment: oh, yeah. my bad. I have declared `.starting` instead of `$scope.start`. haha.. thanks...